# Some troops not levelling up with donation upgrade

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm in a level 6 clan. Everything I donate to other people levels up by 1 level but I have noticed that some donations we receive remain at level 1. I have received level 1 barbs and archers when I request troops. How is this possible? They should be levelling up to level 2 surely? I'm not clan hopping so I am receiving them in my clan.